# Function to count how many times any arbitrary function equates to $0$ within a specific range?

Tags: calculus, functions, computational-mathematics

Suppose I have an unknown function, $f(x)$ which equals zero from time to time.

Is there a function, $g(f(x), a)$ which can tell me how many times $f(x)$ equates to $0$ in the range $[0,a]$?

I need to use a function like this for something I'm working on, if one doesn't exist does anyone have any idea how I might go about making one? I'm assuming sigma sums and integrals are likely to be involved.

Comment: Sure there is such a function: you just described it.  Are you asking whether there's a standard name or notation for this function?  One possibility would be $g(f,a) = |f^{-1}(\{0\}) \cap [0,a]|$.

Comment: @NateEldredge I was looking more for something in closed form that I could insert any function into, I was assuming maybe an integral to check all the values and sigma sum to "count" but not sure how I might construct it.

Comment: is your function continuous, differentiable? If not continuous take $f(x)=1$ for rational $x$, $f(x)=0$ otherwise. Looks like equals $0$ continuum many times (though I am puzzled myself, what "from time to time" would mean in this example). On the other hand if $f$ is constant $0$ function on $[0,a]$ do you consider that it is $0$ just once (once $0$ it stays like that), or continuum many times?

Comment: I don't think that is a computable function that does what you want.

Comment: Perhaps something like $\sum_{x \in [0,a]} 1_{f(x) = 0}$?

Comment: "how many times" - is this a "sampled signal"? Is it crossing "0" or touching zero at a point?

Comment: Is the function positive?

Comment: @Moti the many various functions, f(x)'s, that I would use this master function with, would all be touching zero at various points, similar to how sin^2(x) does. Yes the functions will be positive and all will be continuous except some of them at x=0.

Comment: Nate Elderdge is right. You can define such a function easily, as he has already given two examples. But these are just mathematical formulations of the same definition you gave. Can you describe what use you need to make of this function? That at least could narrow down the sort of representation that would be useful to you.

Comment: @NateEldredge such a function might not always exist. Take, for example, a function which has infinite roots in a given interval

Comment: Are the functions continuous? The touching means a minimum?

Comment: @Moti Yes and Yes

Comment: Are you looking for a function or algorithm? What is the "real" problem?